# User groups in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

I have a requirement to give permissions to a folder or file to multiple groups. I can do this using acl but acl is not present on our system. What other alternative do i have?

I have to do this at runtime

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor may help. They are much less obvious than regular Unix permissions.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new group. Let's call it `combinedgroup`
2. Add to this group all users of the groups to whom you want to give permission.
3. `chgrp combinedgroup /path/to/folder`
4. `chmod 0770 /path/to/folder` (or `0750` for read-only access)

Comment: Note: SU wants to do it at runtime

Comment: but this will override existing group settings, my requirement is to add multiple groups to single folder

Comment: @Sirish Kumar: Not really possible under *NIX permissions.

Answer (score 1):

With the base unix permission system it's not possible for files or folders to have multiple groups. The one hackish way I could think of is to have a pam module that adds users of the other groups to these folders groups on login. Maybe http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-script/ could be used for this.

I don't think it's a good idea but could be worth a try. And this assumes you have root access.